# Angular ui-route with JSON Data Request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, angularjs

I want to build a Single Page Website, where my data is stored in a CMS. This CMS accepts Ajax Requests to serve me JSON. This JSON I want to output in my `ng-app` using the `ui-router` (I also tried the `ngRoute` before, with same results).

The Problem is: I need no template. Cause all my data I need comes from the JSON Request. But using no template or `templateUrl` doesn't affects the controller.

The question is how to output my received data in the HTML? I cant use `ng-controller` because it binds on only this specific controller. `Console.log` shows that my data is successfully received, but I found no way to get an output.

```js
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state('state1', {
                url: '/state1',
                template: '<h1>This Is A State</h1>',
                controller: function($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.pageObj = '';
                    $scope.pageObj.url = '/angular/demo/';
                    $scope.pageObj.class = 'page-my';
                    $scope.pageObj.data = 'Empty';
                    $http
                        .get('/angular/demo/')
                        .then(function(result) {
                            console.log("Data Received");
                            console.log(result.data);
                            $scope.pageObj.data = result.data;
                        });
                    //console.log(result.data);
                    console.log("Hello state");
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: put that json in factory and use weatherer you want

Comment: @Benjamin, Do you want to display data from server when change a state to another? Or do you want to display data on a click?

Comment: change the template to this:  **template: '<h1>This Is A State {{pageObj.data}}</h1>',** and see the angular margic works

Comment: @Jesús Quintana No thats not working. I tried already.

Comment: @Abhilash P A I want to make a request when state is changing, to get my content. Displaying data means all my data is already requested, that would be a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a small solution with using factory. The question is still, how do I access my data? Data now is stored by an own controller i guess. I post my updated code below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.router']).factory("dataService", function($http) {
   var data = "";
   var getData = function() {
    return data;
   }

   var setData = function(newData) {
    data = newData;
   }

   return {
    getData: getData,
    setData: setData
   };

  });

  app.controller('FactoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'dataService', function($scope, $http, dataService) {
   $scope.mydata = dataService.getData();
   console.log($scope.mydata);
  }]);

  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
   $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
     url: '/state1',
     template: '<h1>{{pageObj.data}}</h1>',
     controller: function($scope, $http, dataService) {
      $scope.pageObj = '';
      $scope.pageObj.url = '/angular/demo/';
      $scope.pageObj.class = 'page-my';
      $scope.pageObj.data = 'Empty';
      $http
       .get('/angular/demo/')
       .then(function(result) {
        console.log("Data Received");
        $scope.pageObj.data = result.data;
        //$scope.model.data = dataService.getData();
        dataService.setData("a string");
        //console.log(dataService.getData());
       });
      console.log("Hello state");
     }
    });
  });
```